# 'this'/scope problem in Backbone legacy app, that _.bind isn't solving

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

For an inherited, 7-year-old Backbone site, I have a view "PaymentInfoForm" in which I need to implement a new widget for handling online payments. The new widget (let's call it inceptionLib) is basically a third-party UI & validation wrapper to a fourth-party API. inceptionLib is brand new, proprietary, and not well documented, so it's quite an opaque black box, but I can get it working fine in standalone demo JavaScript. Trying to integrate with Backbone, though, is giving me trouble.

inceptionLib requires me to create a new function, inceptionLibFieldListener, as part of my PaymentInfoForm view, to handle state changes when the user interacts with the widget. What I need to do, in that function, is be able to set a couple of the properties of my view. I am having problems with the 'this' keyword. I understand that 'this' loses scope for my view when used in an inner function, but I'm not sure why that's happening here (unless it's to do with something inside that black box!). And if I attempt to wrap my function in _.bind as the common solution to that type of problem, 'this' just becomes a reference to the window object—as if it "skips a level" upward in my object model. I cannot figure out how to force 'this' to be my view—the same way it is for the very next function—so that I can modify my view properties from here.

It feels like inceptionLib is hijacking 'this' and, well, I really need it back! Any help appreciated.

```
App.PaymentInfoForm = Backbone.View.extend({ // existing view

    oldProperty1: null, // existing property
    myNewProperty2: null, // new property that I need to modify from inceptionLibFieldListener()

    initialize: function (){...}, // create objects & stuff, doesn't matter

    render: function(){ // render, including putting the inceptionLib widget on the page
        {...}
        var inceptionLibForm = inceptionLib.createForm();
        var that = this;
        vgsForm.initInceptionLib().then(function(){
            inceptionLibForm.renderCreditCard('#cc-container', that.inceptionLibFieldListener); 
            inceptionLibForm.renderExpirationDate('#exp-container', that.inceptionLibFieldListener);
        })
        return this;
    },  

    inceptionLibFieldListener: function(newState, prevState, flags) { // inceptionLib listener function
        console.log(this); // result is output for the inceptionLib object
    },
    
    // if I change the inceptionLibFieldListener to this:
    inceptionLibFieldListener: _.bind(function(newState, prevState, flags) { // _.bind should fix it
        console.log(this); // but result is Window object
    // }, this),
    
    somethingElse: function(){ // unrelated function just to test the difference in 'this' 
        console.log(this); // result is console output for the view, as expected
    },
    
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem comes from a misunderstanding of how `this` works. I will not go into a detailed explanation of `this`, because MDN has a [good, comprehensive article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) on the subject. However, I can explain in short why your code is not working and how to fix it.

When you do

```js
var that = this;
vgsForm.initInceptionLib().then(function(){
    inceptionLibForm.renderCreditCard('#cc-container', that.inceptionLibFieldListener); 
    inceptionLibForm.renderExpirationDate('#exp-container', that.inceptionLibFieldListener);
})
```

`that` ensures that `inceptionLibFieldListener` is obtained from the `PaymentInfoForm` instance, which is half of what you were trying to achieve. Doing `x.aMethod`, however, does not *bind* `aMethod` to `x`. In other words, when `aMethod` runs, `this` can still be anything. The following code demonstrates this:

```js
var x = {
    aMethod: function() {
        console.log(this.aProperty);
    },
    aProperty: 1
};

var y = {
    aProperty: 2
};

var aMethod = x.aMethod; // correct function but not bound

aMethod(); // prints undefined
aMethod.call(y); // prints 2
x.aMethod(); // prints 1
```

You may wonder how it can be that `aMethod` *does* appear to be bound to `x` in the last example. Why does `x.aMethod()` work but not `aMethod = x.aMethod; aMethod()`? Why don't you always need to call `aMethod.call(x)`? This is because the JavaScript engine recognizes `x.aMethod(a, b, c)` as a special case and converts it to `x.aMethod.call(x, a, b, c)` automatically. You may find this counterintuitive, and you would have a point, but this is just how JS happens to work.

When you do

```js
inceptionLibFieldListener: _.bind(function(newState, prevState, flags) { // _.bind should fix it
    console.log(this); // but result is Window object
}, this)
```

The problem is that `this` is evaluated outside of any function context. `this` at global scope is always the `window` object, or `undefined` in ES6 module scope. So the `_.bind` is doing what it's supposed to do, but you're passing it the wrong `this`.

There are two things you can do to fix this. The first option is to use `_.bind` at a more opportune moment, when `this` does have the value that you need, for example inside your `render` method:

```js
var boundInceptionFieldListener = _.bind(this.inceptionLibFieldListener, this);
vgsForm.initInceptionLib().then(function(){
    inceptionLibForm.renderCreditCard('#cc-container', boundInceptionFieldListener); 
    inceptionLibForm.renderExpirationDate('#exp-container', boundInceptionFieldListener);
})
```

Another option is to use [`_.bindAll`](https://underscorejs.org/#bindAll), which permanently changes the method to always be bound to your `PaymentInfoForm` instance. This is something you can do inside your `contructor` or `initialize` method, although I don't recommend this if you might also want to use the method in unbound form:

```js
_.bindAll(this, 'inceptionLibFieldListener');
```

With the latter approach, your existing `render` code should work as-is.